# SharePoint Workflow "InternalServerError" when try to move a document using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

When I try to move document between libraries of same site using rest api, it shows **"InternelServerError"**, **file not move**, **but workflow status is completed.**

Note: Both are created by using same templates.

My Header:
Accept:application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type:application/json;odata=verbose
Request-Type:HTTP POST

Rest api is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the account which trigger the workflow has proper permissions on the target library. Please check the permission of the account on the target library and try to grant the account full control on the library, then test again.

In addition, please check if there is any message about this issue in workflow history list and the event viewer of the workflow manager server.